# If $\sum_k |a_k|<\infty$ and $z_{n}\to z$, then $\lim_{n}\sum_{k}a_{k}z_{n}^{k}=\sum_{k}a_{k}z^{k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, circles, uniform-convergence

Let $(a_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\in\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$ and let $(z_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $S^{1}:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ that converges to $z$. Is it then true that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{k}z_{n}^{k}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{k}z^{k}?$$ I was hoping to use compactness of $S^{1}$ and some uniform convergence argument. However, I'm not even sure whether the sum converges uniformly or not.

By the way, I'm trying to avoid measure theoreretic arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\Big|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kz^k_n-\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kz^n\Big|\le 
\Big|\sum_{k=1}^N a_kz^k_n-\sum_{k=1}^N a_kz^n\Big|
+\Big|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty a_kz^k_n-\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty a_kz^n\Big|\\ \le \Big|\sum_{k=1}^N a_kz^k_n-\sum_{k=1}^N a_kz^n\Big|+\Big|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty a_kz^k_n\Big|+\Big|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty a_kz^n\Big| \\
\le \Big|\sum_{k=1}^N a_k(z^k_n-z^k)\Big|+
2\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+
\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
To achieve the above, first find $N\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4},
$$
and then find $n_0\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
n\ge n_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |a_k||z^k_n-z^k|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2N}, \quad \text{for all $k=1,\ldots,N$.}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the way I can only use measure theoretic argument, sorry about that: $|a_{k}z_{n}^{k}|=|a_{k}|$ and $(a_{k})\in l^{1}$, so by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem the limit and the sum can be swiped.

Comment: Does measure theory needed to state and prove Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem not use the limit/sum interversion ?